# Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Tags: r, spatial, geor, covariogram

I try to plot the variogram in R. When I run the below code:

```
library(geoR)
Data = as.geodata(Data2, coords.col=1:2, data.col=3)
VG = variog(Data2,estimator.type="classical")
VG.fit =   variofit(VG, ini.cov.pars =c(0.095,1.4), cov.model="gaussian",  fix.nugget=FALSE, nugget=0.065)
plot(VG.fit)
```

I am getting an error:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' is a list, but
>   does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `VG` is of class `variogram` while `VG.fit` is of classes `variomodel` and `variofit`. There is a plot method for `variogram`, but not for `variomodel` or `variofit`. After reading some documentation, it seems that you should plot the `variogram` first:

```
plot(VG)
lines(VG.fit)
```

If you only want the fitted line, then add `pch = ""` to the plot function as an argument.